# How do i copy text from a command prompt into a txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the output to be a complete copy of the cmd in the command prompt but I keep getting 0 as my output

```
import os
print(os.system('netstat -ano'))
```

Comment: You *cannot* do this with `os.system()` - the output goes directly to your terminal, Python never sees it at all.  Look at the `subprocess` module instead, there are several usable options there.

Answer (score 0):

You can either write the file directly with Python or you can pipe the output of running the Python script to a file.  For making system calls, it is better to use `subprocess`

```
import subprocess

proc = suprocess.Popen(['netstat', '-ano'])
out, err = proc.communicate()

with open('netstat.txt', 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(out)
```

Or to pipe to a file:

```
python myscript.py > netstat.txt
```